# Is a good idea to use a reset stylesheet in a started project?

Tags: css, stylesheet, reset

I'm working in a long started web project that not use a reset stylesheet.

It will be a good idea to include a reset stylesheet given all the things already done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project already works fine, and renders properly in all major browsers, don't worry about a reset sheet. For future case, use reset sheets to quickly set aside browser-differences, and allow yourself to focus on more important things.

Contrary to what others here have mentioned, don't ever use `* {margin:0;padding:0}`. Instead, I would suggest using Eric Meyers' Reset Stylesheet. It's well-respected by the community of professionals, and has even found itself included in some of the most used css-frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Meh.

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

has always worked just fine for me. But it depends on the nature of the website... if you want a pixel-perfect design, then maybe a reset would be helpful, if you have a more fluid layout... I wouldn't sweat it. I prefer to only reset the elements I'm actually using or need to appear a certain way, and let everything else be "native".

Answer (score 2):

Yes i always reset it using [The CSS Reset File](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/)

Comment: I favor Meyers' reset, but I'll still up-vote you for using a reset ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea only if you are ready to check every pages on your web :)